# Open shift login issue with rhc

Tags: ruby, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

Am facing issue while login to openshift account through rhc. However i can able to login using web console not through rhc. It throws wrong user name and password. Am 100% sure am using right user name and password. From debug mode understood its trying to access "https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user", do we need separate level of access for this?

I have checked express.conf, default_rhlogin is my login id. It looks good.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line for OpenShift Origin is called `oc`, not `rhc`. The `rhc` command line client is for older OpenShift V2. Origin is V3.

See the online tutorial at https://learn.openshift.com/ about logging into a V3 cluster.